# google adsense - sometimes all ads are visible in page, sometimes I see transparent boxes

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

I have placed 3 google ad scripts in my site. They are really nice but sometimes for example I see 2 of 3, or 1 of 3.

I just wanted to make sure that this is coming from google adsense's behavior. Is it like that or maybe it is coming from my website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adsense shows ads based on your ip and if they are available. Check your website stats and compair them with the stats of Adsense.
It is probably normal behaviour.